# Why is the Heatmap Leaflet in Map not showing up?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, leaflet, react-leaflet

**SITUATION IMAGE:**
[image]
[image]

---

**SITUATION:**
Not showing heatMap in my Map not showing properly.

1. What have I done wrong ?
2. Why doesn't the Heatmap Leaflet appear on the Map?

And part `heatmapLayer.setData(FeatureCollection);` if removed heatmapLayer so `setData(FeatureCollection);` it pops up but instead appears a **marker** on the map like this:
[image]

---

**CODE:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useRef } from "react";
import { GeoJSON } from "react-leaflet";
import { useRecoilValue, useSetRecoilState } from "recoil";
import HeatmapOverlay from "leaflet-heatmap";
import { arcgisToken } from "../recoil";
import { mapBounds, loadingMap } from "../state";
import { getLocationCity } from "../data/arcgis";
import "leaflet.heat";

export default function HSales() {
    const [data, setData] = useState();
    const setIsLoading = useSetRecoilState(loadingMap);
    const bounds = useRecoilValue(mapBounds);
    const tokenArcgis = useRecoilValue(arcgisToken);
    const geoJsonLayer = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchDataSpeedtestKel = () => {
            const body = {
                returnGeometry: true,
                rollbackOnFailure: true,
                geometry: JSON.stringify({
                    xmin: bounds.west,
                    ymin: bounds.south,
                    xmax: bounds.east,
                    ymax: bounds.north,
                    spatialReference: { wkid: 4326 },
                }),
                geometryType: "esriGeometryEnvelope",
                token: tokenArcgis,
            };

            setIsLoading(true);
            getLocationCity(body)
                .then((response) => {
                    const array = [];
                    response.features.forEach((element) => {
                        array.push({
                            type: "Feature",
                            properties: element["attributes"],
                            geometry: {
                                type: "Point",
                                coordinates: [
                                    element["geometry"]["x"],
                                    element["geometry"]["y"],
                                ],
                            },
                        });
                    });

                    const FeatureCollection = {
                        type: "FeatureCollection",
                        features: array,
                    };

                    if (geoJsonLayer.current) {
                        geoJsonLayer.current.clearLayers().addData(FeatureCollection);
                    }

                    var cfg = {
                        radius: 0.1,
                        maxOpacity: 1,
                        scaleRadius: true,
                        useLocalExtrema: true,
                        latField: "x",
                        lngField: "y",
                    };

                    var heatmapLayer = new HeatmapOverlay(cfg);

                    setData(FeatureCollection);
                    // setData(FeatureCollection);
                })
                .catch((err) => console.log(err))
                .finally(() => setIsLoading(false));
        };

        fetchDataSpeedtestKel();
    }, [bounds, setIsLoading, tokenArcgis]);

    if (data) {
        return (
            <>
                <GeoJSON
                    ref={geoJsonLayer}
                    data={data}
                />
            </>
        );
    }
}
```

your response from **getLocationCity** in the example:

```
export const getLocationCity = async (params) => {
  try {
    const body = DataCustom(params);
    const result = await instanceArcgis.post(
      "/rest/HomeLocation/4/query",
      body,
    );
    return await result?.data;
  }
```

---

Earlier I read and sample coding via the link:

1. https://www.patrick-wied.at/static/heatmapjs/example-heatmap-leaflet.html
2. https://codesandbox.io/s/suspicious-chandrasekhar-sybk67?file=/src/index.js